# netrw: ftplugin double loaded?

Tags: netrw

I notice an annoying stutter when opening directories. Just a split second, but it's kind of a problem if I'm navigating the directory tree and it hesitates each time I open a different directory.

I thought it might be double-loading something so to debug, I put the following in `~/.vim/ftplugin/netrw.vim`:

```
if !exists('s:count')
  let s:count = 0
endif
let s:count += 1

func! Count()
  echo s:count
endf
```

and mapped `<leader>j` to call `Count()`.

If I open a file in vim, and run `:edit %:h`, a netrw buffer opens with the file's containing directory as expected. The `s:count` is 2, so my ftplugin was indeed double-loaded. Hitting Enter on a listing to edit that file increments `s:count` by 1 more.

It's consistent: every time navigate into a directory-buffer, `s:count` increments by 2, every time I navigate down the file-tree, `s:count` increments by 1. This also means that if move down the tree into a subdirectory, it increments by 3.

Is this a good indicator that something is loading more times than necessary, and if so how might I fix it?

Comment: what vim version are you testing with?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I'm testing on Vim 8.0.0705 and Neovim 0.2.0_1.
 
I noticed it a while back, but it seems Vim no longer stutters (but still seems to be double-loading the ftplugin file), though Neovim continues to stutter. I looked through recent Vim releases to see if a fix was mentioned but didn't see anything.

Comment: there was a patch to fix double loading of filetypes just recently. Neovim probably doesn't have it yet

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Interesting, do you know which patch it was? I'm looking through the recent vim [releases](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases) as well as `:help netrw-history` but can't find any mention of it. According to my (maybe flawed?) debugging technique above, Vim is still double loading, but it no longer causes any noticeable hesitation.

Comment: Was thinking of patches [649](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.0.0649) and [650](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.0.0650), but seems they specifically fixed only the help filetype. You might want to ask Charles (maintainer of netrw) or on vim-dev for further advise

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Will do. Thanks for the help!